# Running Azure Web job on a timer

Tags: azure, timer, azure-webjobs

If a web job takes more than the interval between runs , will azure start a new instance or it will wait until the job is complete to start it again ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will wait until the job is completed. We could get answer from [TimerTrigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger). The following the snippet from the document.

> If your function execution takes longer than the timer interval, **another execution won't be triggered until after the current invocation completes**. The next execution is scheduled after the current execution completes.